# Using CE Image on a php generated image

Tags: ce-image

I have a php file that generates an image based on some parameters. But it doesn't seem like CE Image knows how to handle that.

The URL looks something like this: `myimg.php?id=165`

It's being served as an image: `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

When viewing it in the browser it shows the image like it's supposed to. It also works with the `<img>`-tag, so there's nothing wrong with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the source that is being passed into CE Image is not an actual image on the file system, you'll want CE Image to treat it as a remote image. You can accomplish that by using the parameter [force_remote=](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#force_remote)"y".

Here's an example:

```
{exp:ce_img:singe src="http://example.com/myimg.php?id=165" width="100" force_remote="y"}
```

Comment: I'm only getting an error message: `CE Image debug: Unknown image format.`

Comment: Do you have any examples of this working? With a corresponding php-file? Right now I'm outputting a base 64-encoded bytearray
`$img = base64_encode($something[$idFromUrl]); echo $img;`

Comment: Oh, wow, I totally messed up. I'm working on localhost, which of course doesn't work with `force_remote`. It works when I publish it. Thanks!